# Missing values when serializing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to serialize this form via `jQuery("#feedback-form").serialize();`

It returns only `"z_name=&z_requester=&z_description="` no matter what actually is in the input-fields and textarea.

```
<form id="feedback-form" method="POST" name="former">
    <div id="box-form">
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="z_name"></p>
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" name="z_requester"></p>
        <p><textarea cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Message" name="z_description"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Abschicken" id="submitter"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show where and How are you using `jQuery("#feedback-form").serialize()`

Comment: you have no input value see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Lbkfger/1/

Comment: @Sel Vaa input value shouldn't matter see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pLua944c/

Comment: I cut-and-pasted your exact code into a local test HTML file and ran `jQuery("#feedback-form").serialize();` in the Firebug console and got: `"z_name=My+Name&z_requester=me%40here.com&z_description=Just+talking+to+myself."` when I put in some random data.  So, the code works by itself . . . can you show us the rest of your JS around your `serialize()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to change `<p><input type="submit" value="Abschicken" id="submitter"></p>` and try a button instead `<p><button type="submit">Test</button></p>`

the js code into

```
$('#feedback-form').submit(function(evemt){
    $('#console').html( $('#feedback-form').serialize() );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Type some value and it's work fine, please refer to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/sg9cutvy/)

Answer (score 0):

I had missing inputs when serializing a form because I forgot to add a `name` property on the inputs (I just had an `id`).

(This was not the original poster's problem, but matches the title.)